# How to create a loop in mac terminal to touch files in reverse order

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to touch the files in a directory so that the first file in the directory (by alphabetical ordering) was touched last.

I am having trouble even referencing the current directory in the function. I've tried:

for f in $PWD ; touch  f; done

and this returns an error. But I think this would, even if it worked, be touching the files in order, and I want to do this in reverse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse a for loop in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675910/how-to-reverse-a-for-loop-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

That fragment `for f in $PWD` can't work, because `$PWD` gives you the name of a directory, not a list of the files in the directory.

I would try something like

```
ls | sort -r | while read filename; do touch "$filename"; sleep 1; done
```

`ls` gives you a list of files.  `sort -r` sorts it into reverse order.  And then the `while read filename; do ... done` loop does something for each filename.  I put a `sleep` call in the loop to ensure the files will actually end up with different timestamps.